# Issue on Setting Bootstrap list inline Class with Thumbnails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/x7wbtmw8/3/) and let me know why I am not able to set all thumbnails in a list with `.list-inline`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3">

                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="holder.js/300x300" alt="..." />
                            <div class="caption">
                                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                <p>...</p>
                         <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="holder.js/300x300" alt="..." />
                            <div class="caption">
                                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                                <p>...</p>
                             <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3">

                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="holder.js/300x300" alt="..." />
                            <div class="caption">
                                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                                <p>...</p>
                             <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I used the list-inline class with my ul list to have all thumbnails in one line (doesn't matter to be hidden) but Bootstrap still acting responsively and send the overflow items to second line and so on

Comment: I removed my answer but I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  Maybe if you create an image or find an example that has what you want it would help.

Comment: This is working normally. http://jsfiddle.net/x7wbtmw8/5/ but why do you have another wrapper, what is the point of putting this in a list. Just more markup for no reason.